# Ramayana and Gayathri Mantra

Tags: ramayana, gayatri-mantra

What is the significance between Ramayana and Gayathri Mantra? The essence of the epic is having a pivotal role with the gayatri mantra.

Comment: I think the word similarity is more correct than significance.That will show the connection or link between both.

Comment: @swift pushkar will give the answer by evening.

Comment: The first letter of every 1000th Shloka of the Ramayana together make up the Gayatri Mantra!

There are 24 letters in the Gayatri Mantra and there are 24,000 Shlokas in the Valmiki Ramayana. The first letter of every 1000th Shloka together of the Ramayana forms the Gayatri Mantra, making this revered mantra the essence of the epic. While the Gayatri Mantra has been actually first mentioned in the Rig Veda, it has gained significance thanks to the Ramayana.

Source: Shri Vishal Kamlani  who is a writer for youth connect.

Comment: See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15252/3500).