# Is the story of Shunahshepa an allegory?

Tags: interpretation, story

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunahshepa

mentions some scriptures it occurs in and some interpretations.

(1) does his name mean "dog penis"?  why was he given that name?

(2) is there consensus as to the interpretation of the story?

Comment: The name might just be a namesake to denote that for his parents he was maybe equivalent to a .. that thing. So that's why they gave him up for sacrifice so easily. Or it could actually be his original name also. In any case, Vishwamitra did a good thing in renaming him as Devaraata.

Comment: [Check this](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/index.php?mode=3&direct=au&script=hk&tran_input=Shunahshepa)

Comment: Closely Related: [Contradictions between Ramayana and Aitareya Brahmana while describing about Shunahshepa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35805/contradictions-between-ramayana-and-aitareya-brahmana-while-describing-about-shu). Also check out [this paper](https://archive.org/details/Rigvedic_Legends_Through_the_Ages_Hariyappa/page/n131/mode/2up). The base story appears to be historical with the name itself having a different/positive connotation ('a pillar of happiness') early on but during/after the brahmana period it changed.

Comment: From where did you get the meaning as "dog penis"? For dog the word should be संस्कृतम् Sanskrit meaning of 'dog' · = कुक्कुरः | kukkur: · = शुनक | shunak