# the ramayana book

Tags: ramayana

Ramayana is the story of Lord Ram, and I have come with a deep passion for reading the epic story of Lord Ram, and as far as I know it was written by Valmiki during Mother Sita's stay at the ashram, but I'm so very confused, because I find all these names with the Ramayana that makes it seem like Ramayana has types. So please help me clear this.

First of all I find things like **Valmiki Ramayana(which I think should be the original and the only Ramayana, if others exist I think only translations should exist)**, but I found others names like `Kamba Ramayana`, and maybe others exist but I don't know.

And, I thought the Ramayana should be one big book, but, I've asked people around and they attach a `kanda` to the book, like the `bal kanda`, `yuddha kanda`, are these `table of contents` in the ramayana, and is this created by the `valmiki` himself, or is this later done by later scholars, and if it is done by later scholars,

- how much of the original work of valmiki is still there remaining
  because such literary modifications often detoriate the orginal work.
- Which version of `Ramayana` book should I try to read.
- How much of the original of `valmiki` work is still remaining, and
- what would be the way to study the true valmiki's work?

Comment: You will never get correct information in response to this question, as this subject has multiple answers.@mathmaniage

Comment: @srimannarayanakv , really, but, it's not opinion based, after all the book's division to kandas (is it even a division) is probably recent I think(just logically)

Comment: @srimannarayanakv , and everyone knows valmiki as the original author but, there should not be an opion based answer for what the other books are

Comment: I never said the question is opinion based.  The available Valmiki Ramayana contains many interpolations.  Some people will accept that there are many interpolations, but many think otherwise.  It is a controversial subject@mathmaniage

Comment: You can go through this answer (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34970/3869  ) @mathmaniage

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, and could you also explain what are these `kandas`, are these   of the valmiki ramayana created by valmiki himself?

Comment: very difficult to answer, as to whether the division was done by him or by somebody else at a later date.@mathmaniage