# Confirmation on the number of verses in different editions of the Valmiki Ramayana

Tags: ramayana, shloka, valmiki, critical-edition, recension

There is a slight confusion In the number of verses attributed to different edition of the Valmiki Ramayana in the critical edition published by BORI.

As regards the critical edition, the [critical edition](https://archive.org/details/RmyaaCriticalEdition7EDUPShah1975/page/n65/mode/2up), itself says that it comprises 18766 verses; but Bibek Debroy in his [translation of the critical edition](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24442) says that the very same BORI edition contains 18,670 verses. A difference of 96 verses between the two.

The canto-wise break up of verses in the critical edition along with a comparison with the Vulgate (most commonly used edition) and Kumbhakonam edition is given as follows:

| Canto | CE | Debroy | Vulgate | Kumbha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Bala** | *1943* | *1941* | 2266 | 2242 |
| **Ayodhya** | 3160 | 3160 | 4343 |  |
| **Aranya** | *2068* | *2060* | 2469 | 2842 |
| **Kishkindha** | *1984* | *1898* | 2455 |  |
| **Sundara** | 2487 | 2487 | 2826 |  |
| **Yuddha** | 4435 | 4435 | 5710 |  |
| **Uttara** | 2689 | 2689 | 3980 |  |
| **Total** | 18,766 | 18,670 | 24,049 | 24,272 |

The above figures of column 2, 4 and 5 have been sourced from the critical edition of BORI (linked above).

**Reason for asking Question**
Normally a person would trust what the edition itself says, but a doubt in this case arises because the critical edition itself has given different figures for itself in different places (preface of each canto), they are:

1. Bala: 1941 (in the [Bala Kanda CE](https://archive.org/details/RmyaaCriticalEdition1EDGHBhatt1960/page/n33/mode/2up)).
2. Ayodhya: 3170 (in the [Ayodhya kanda CE](https://archive.org/details/RmyaaCriticalEdition2EDPLVaidya1962/page/n27/mode/2up)).
3. Aranya: 2066 (in the [Aranya Kanda CE](https://archive.org/details/RmyaaCriticalEdition3EDPCDivanji1963/page/n29/mode/2up)).

Yuddha Kanda matches and other canto-wise figures (especially Kishkindha kanda where there is major difference) before each canto are not stated. Since the critical edition contradicts itself in each Kanda and giving due credit to Bibek Debroy‘s efforts, his figures cannot be brushed aside. Further the critical edition being self-contradictory could raise a possible doubt on the number of verses attributed to the Vulgate and Kumbhakonam edition (as per one independent calculation from a site, there was a difference in the vulgate and as per [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15252) there are 24,253 verses in the Kumbhakonam edition). Accordingly,

**Question:**
Would like a confirmation on the actual canto-wise number of verses in the Critical Edition and the Vulgate, both. Please confirm the number of sargas of both too (can be found in the link above).

Another request would be to include a confirmation on the canto-wise number of verses contained in the Kumbhakonam recension (which, as per the CE, overall contains 223 verses more than the Vulgate) along with the number of sargas in each canto.

---

Please note (help with sargas): Vulgate has 645 sargas, Kumbhakonam has 649 and CE has 606 sargas

Comment: Who believes in critical editions anyway? Traditional religious followers? No ; Couple of users on this site? Yes may be

Comment: Could at least some of these numbers be printing errors?

Comment: @Rickross yes exactly. But the thing is sometimes new followers tend to get swayed by the flowery words of the leftists funding/ making such editions. Necessary to clarify and give a correct direction to new followers and also clear my own doubts just in case. wonder why we allow them to do so?? :)

Comment: @Surya yes it’s likely and that’s why the question: what is the correct number of verses?? Which of the figures is a misprint?

Comment: Who decided 'BORI' was the 'critical edition'?? There are many recensions of Valmiki's Ramayana.