# Can anyone tell Kands in Valmiki Ramayan in descending order in size?

Tags: ramayana

Please tell in order of biggest to smallest in terms of size in terms of shlokas

Comment: What do you mean by size: number of Sargas (chapters) or Shlokas?

Comment: @YDS I mean Shlokas

Comment: Does this answer your query.... Specially the last two answers in this particular question. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15249/26679