# what is the longest an smallest kand in valmiki ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, rama, bhakti, sita, valmiki

According to Valmiki Ramayana, there are 7 kands. what is the largest and smallest kand? and what about sargas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many shlokas are there in Valmiki Ramayana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15249/how-many-shlokas-are-there-in-valmiki-ramayana)