# What are some well-written and accurate Ramayana books based on Valmiki's original work?

Tags: ramayana, translation-request, book-recommendation

What are some well-written and accurate Ramayana books that I can use?

By accurate I mean those that stay true to Valmiki's original Sansrkit work.

Comment: Try reading at http://www.valmikiramayan.net or https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in for free. Also see: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2506

Comment: If you want abridged versions, Ramayana by Rajagopalachari and Ramayana by Ramesh menon are good books.